# Part number for rubber beading in engine bay - VW Polo Mk5

Tags: vw, polo, seal, rubber

This is a VW Polo Mk5 from 2015. I noticed that the engine bay has a rubber seal around the leaf guard that has fallen off. What is the part number for this rubber seal?

This is my car

[image]
[image]

This is how it should look (notice the thick rubber seal) at the lower end of the cowl. This also holds the cowl in place from the lower end.

[image]

Comment: Have you checked with your VW dealer or one of the many VW parts online suppliers?

Comment: A generic replacement part may be in order here, just due to the affordability factor.